# Ember.js parse error

Tags: ember.js, handlebars.js

I keep getting a parse error uing Ember.js... and I really can't figure where it's from. It seems to die at every {{#link-to}}...

Also, my routes are corrects, it worked before and I didn't change it...

**Here is the templates where the error come from :**

```
<script type="text/x-handlebars" id="settings">
    <ul class="nav nav-tabs">
        {{#link-to "settings.users"          tagName="li"}}<a {{bindAttr href="view.href"}}><?php echo __("Users"); ?></a>{{/link-to}}
        {{#link-to "lifestyles"              tagName="li"}}<a {{bindAttr href="view.href"}}><?php echo __("Lifestyles"); ?></a>{{/link-to}}
        {{#link-to "supplements"             tagName="li"}}<a {{bindAttr href="view.href"}}><?php echo __("Supplements"); ?></a>{{/link-to}}
        {{#link-to "medications"             tagName="li"}}<a {{bindAttr href="view.href"}}><?php echo __("Medications"); ?></a>{{/link-to}}
        {{#link-to "settings.disciplines"    tagName="li"}}<a {{bindAttr href="view.href"}}><?php echo __("Disciplines"); ?></a>{{/link-to}}
        {{#link-to "settings.assurances"     tagName="li"}}<a {{bindAttr href="view.href"}}><?php echo __("Assurances"); ?></a>{{/link-to}}
    </ul>
    {{outlet}}
</script>
```

**The console output here :**

[image]

**EDIT :**

When my PHP session is off, everything is alright, looks like the error in on my Cake's side...

Answer (score 0):

It looks like your template is being entity escaped somewhere.  Based on the console error, it seems that `"` has been replaced with `&quot;`.  Do you have some sort of build tool messing with the templates before they are compiled by handlebars?

Comment: Hard to say without seeing a running example.  The arrow in the console error is pointing to the `&` of `&quot;`, so I'm fairly sure that some entity escaping is happening somewhere.  Any chance you can repro this in a JSBin?